# Change variables between scenes unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene where I write down my player stats. In the next scene (basically in the next 2 scenes but it doesn't matter) I want to buy some weapons and change the variables.

The thing is I'm saving the object with "DontDestroyOnLoad" and when I go to the next scene I want to find out how can I change the variables.

First Scene:

[image]

The code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class statsTextsToDisplayAndChanges : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static statsTextsToDisplayAndChanges _INstance;
    buyWeapons bw;
    public Text m_LevelText;
    public Text m_AttackText;
    public Text m_DefendText;
    public Text m_MoneyText;
    public int level = 0;
    public int money = 500;
    public int health = 400;
    public int attack = 10;
    public int def = 5;
    string answer;
    string url = "http://alex3685.dx.am/display.php";


    public int sword1 = 200;


    public void Start()
    {

        _INstance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);

        display();

    }

    public void display()
    {


        m_LevelText.text = level.ToString();
        m_AttackText.text = attack.ToString();
        m_DefendText.text = def.ToString();
        m_MoneyText.text = money.ToString();
    }

    public void onPurchase()
    {
        if (money >= sword1)
        {
            Debug.Log("YOU BOUGHT IT");
            money -= sword1;
            //Destroy(GameObject.Find("playerStats"));
            display();
        }
    }

}
```

Second scene:

[image]

When I press the button the debug.log from the purchase function works but in the text nothing changes (from 500 coins-200 coins of the sword=300 coins).

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm....initial thoughs:

This is one of the times where you want a true manager object with a scrip attached that only knows how to store the relevant stat.

Then, in whatever scripts that handles the purchasing they have a private GameObject with a reference to the manager object.`private GameObject _Manager;`

> But the object exists in another scene in my editor so I cant drag and drop the reference!

No problem, 
Lets say that the object with the component that stores the stats are called `"PlayerManager"`. In the script that handles the purchasing in the start() method add: `_Manager = gameobject.Find("PlayerManager");`

Now you can change all the variables to your hearts content, assuming of course that you have set the variables in the manager to be public, or if you are more advanced and concerned about robust code, you have the proper get;set; methods in place.

Hope this helped!

Comment: wow it helped!Now when i press buy i can see the stats changing!I have one more question now.When i go back to the first scene(picture 1) the stats go back to the old stats
i,e i have 500 coins in the first and in the second when i buy the weapon i have 300 coins.When i'm going back to the first scene i still have 500 coins.Any ideas?

Comment: oh sorry my bad.it doesn't work.it worked because i accidentally duplicate the "playerstats" object in the second scene as well.When i deleted it,it didn't work.

Comment: And this is why you don't use Scenes. You need to have your Manager script detect when an instance already exists, and if so, destroy itself.

Comment: What Draco said. The problem with returning to an earlier scene is that it still behaves as if it is the first time it loads. AKA, the original statObject is going to be there with all the references and scripts. So maybe have an initializing scene in the start that you never go back to and just continue to use dontDestroyOnload().

If you want to go the destroy the other manager way you are going too need a way to tell who is oldest btw. So you should also track how many times the manager object has traveled from one scene to another. and use that stat to decide wicth object to destroy.

Comment: Another swer suggest using payer preffs, but those are stored in a way that makes them easy to edit from outside sourves (hacking) so depending on the scope of your game if you should use it or not depends. If you don¨t care about if the player can change values then use playerPrefs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PlayerPrefs` to save and retrieve data.

Source : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html